# How to determine if the magnetometer needs calibration for CoreMotion reference frames?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion, magnetometer

Apple's documentation for [CMAttitudeReferenceFrame](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical) says that some reference frames "may require device movement to calibrate the magnetometer" but doesn't elaborate.

How can I determine if the magnetometer is currently in need of calibration?

Answer (score 2):

[`CMDeviceMotion.magneticField`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmcalibratedmagneticfield) has a property [`accuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmcalibratedmagneticfield/1615956-accuracy), which is a [`CMMagneticFieldCalibrationAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmmagneticfieldcalibrationaccuracy) enum. If its value is `.uncalibrated` then presumably some device motion is required to calibrate the magnetometer.

The documentation is unclear on whether motion will be helpful if the accuracy is `.low` or `.medium`.